# How to import the drools project to Drools workbench UI?

Tags: java, jboss, drools

I have a working project which i developed using drools 7.1. its working fine

I am using traditional approach for firing the rules.

kSession.fireAllRules();

Now i want the same project to be imported into the workbench. So that i can start working on DSL rules.

I Tried importing through UI.
There is a option to import the project from git repo but the drl file and the folder structure is not readable, all i see is the java files.

Could any one suggest a best approach .